# From CSV, group similar data together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have some data that I'm trying to group together:

```
Serial_Num     Latitude Longitude
1950004S11059   -11.1   59.1
1950004S11059   -11.6   57.8
1950004S11059   -12.4   56
1950004S11059   -13.2   54.6
1950004S11059   -13.8   53.8
1950004S11059   -14.8   52.7
1950004S11059   -15.9   52
1950004S11059   -18.3   52.4
1950004S11059   -20     54
1950004S11059   -22.1   55.9
1950004S11059   -26.2   59.8
1950012S14150   -14     146.9
1950012S14150   -14.4   145.8
1950012S14150   -14.9   145.4
1950012S14150   -15.8   145.6
1950012S14150   -18.9   149.1
1950012S14150   -22.3   152.5
1950013S14139   -16     139
1950013S14139   -16.3   139
```

So simply, for each unique `Serial_Num`, I want the coordinates. I'm expecting something similar to:

```
1950004S11059: {"GPS": (-11.1 , 59.1) , (-11.6, 57.8) , (-12.4, 56), ..., (-26.2, 59.8)}
```

And then I can loop through the `GPS` coordinates for each `Serial_Num` and plot.

I have some scripts that I have used elsewhere, but mainly relies on the .csv data being used to set up a dictionary, with the `Serial_Num` as the key.

However, the data in the csv is sequential, and the sequence is important.

What's a way to output, for each `Serial_Num`, the list of coordinates, in order as they are in the CSV?

Edit: I'm looking at Pandas right now, as it has a `groupBy` method that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way. Breakdown of each step below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df['GPS'] = list(zip(df.Latitude, df.Longitude))
df.groupby('Serial_Num')['GPS'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

**Read the data**

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)

#        Serial_Num  Latitude  Longitude
# 0   1950004S11059     -11.1       59.1
# 1   1950004S11059     -11.6       57.8
# 2   1950004S11059     -12.4       56.0
# 3   1950004S11059     -13.2       54.6
# 4   1950004S11059     -13.8       53.8
# 5   1950004S11059     -14.8       52.7
```

**Make tuple column**

```
df['GPS'] = list(zip(df.Latitude, df.Longitude))

#        Serial_Num  Latitude  Longitude             GPS
# 0   1950004S11059     -11.1       59.1   (-11.1, 59.1)
# 1   1950004S11059     -11.6       57.8   (-11.6, 57.8)
# 2   1950004S11059     -12.4       56.0   (-12.4, 56.0)
# 3   1950004S11059     -13.2       54.6   (-13.2, 54.6)
# 4   1950004S11059     -13.8       53.8   (-13.8, 53.8)
# 5   1950004S11059     -14.8       52.7   (-14.8, 52.7)
```

**Create dictionary**

```
df.groupby('Serial_Num')['GPS'].apply(list).to_dict()

# {'1950004S11059': [(-11.1, 59.100000000000001),
#                    (-11.6, 57.799999999999997),
#                    (-12.4, 56.0),
#                    (-13.199999999999999, 54.600000000000001),
#                    (-13.800000000000001, 53.799999999999997),
#                    (-14.800000000000001, 52.700000000000003),
#                    (-15.9, 52.0),
#                    (-18.300000000000001, 52.399999999999999),
#                    (-20.0, 54.0),
#                    (-22.100000000000001, 55.899999999999999),
#                    (-26.199999999999999, 59.799999999999997)],
#  '1950012S14150': [(-14.0, 146.90000000000001),
#                    (-14.4, 145.80000000000001),
#                    (-14.9, 145.40000000000001),
#                    (-15.800000000000001, 145.59999999999999),
#                    (-18.899999999999999, 149.09999999999999),
#                    (-22.300000000000001, 152.5)],
#  '1950013S14139': [(-16.0, 139.0), (-16.300000000000001, 139.0)]}
```

Comment: **Yes!!** That's amazing.  I am super new to Pandas, but it looks like the `Latitude` in `df.Latitude` is not a set method/word in Pandas, but is the literal header in the file, yes? So if I also had, say, states in there under "State", I could do `zip(df.State,df.Latitude,df.Longitude)`, yeah?  There's a lot going on in those three lines, I'll have to study, but great post/answer, thanks!

Comment: @pylang - when I try that, with a .csv, I get this error: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 901, saw 6`

Comment: @BruceWayne, looks like there's an issue with your csv file. Can you open in a text editor and see what you have in line 901? It could be a comma where it shouldn't be, or something similar. There is a way to ignore bad lines with `pandas` [`error_bad_lines=False`], but this will mean your data may not be complete.

Comment: That's what I thought too - but looking at it, doesn't seem like there's an errant comma, right?  [See screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1iLv.jpg)

Comment: what i would do is paste that line into a separate file, read it into pandas and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 2):

**Given**

A file named `foo.csv`:

```
Serial_Num     Latitude Longitude
1950004S11059   -11.1   59.1
1950004S11059   -11.6   57.8
1950004S11059   -12.4   56
1950004S11059   -13.2   54.6
1950004S11059   -13.8   53.8
1950004S11059   -14.8   52.7
1950004S11059   -15.9   52
1950004S11059   -18.3   52.4
1950004S11059   -20     54
1950004S11059   -22.1   55.9
1950004S11059   -26.2   59.8
1950012S14150   -14     146.9
1950012S14150   -14.4   145.8
1950012S14150   -14.9   145.4
1950012S14150   -15.8   145.6
1950012S14150   -18.9   149.1
1950012S14150   -22.3   152.5
1950013S14139   -16     139
1950013S14139   -16.3   139
```

And some code to parse the data as a tuples of (serial, coordinates):

```
import csv
import collections as ct


def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            #line = [x for x in line[0].split(" ") if x]
            yield line[0], tuple(map(float, line[1:]))
```

**Code**

We build a nesting of [defaultdicts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
data = ct.defaultdict(dict)
for serial, coords in (read_file("foo.csv")):
    if serial not in data:
        dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
    dd["GPS"].append(coords)
    data[serial] = dd

dict(data)
```

Output

```
{'1950004S11059': defaultdict(list,
             {'GPS': [
               (-11.1, 59.1),
               (-11.6, 57.8),
               (-12.4, 56.0),
               (-13.2, 54.6),
               (-13.8, 53.8),
               (-14.8, 52.7),
               (-15.9, 52.0),
               (-18.3, 52.4),
               (-20.0, 54.0),
               (-22.1, 55.9),
               (-26.2, 59.8)]}),
 '1950012S14150': defaultdict(list,
             {'GPS': [
               (-14.0, 146.9),
               (-14.4, 145.8),
               (-14.9, 145.4),
               (-15.8, 145.6),
               (-18.9, 149.1),
               (-22.3, 152.5)]}),
 '1950013S14139': defaultdict(list, 
             {'GPS': [
               (-16.0, 139.0), 
               (-16.3, 139.0)]})}
```

Comment: I tried that with my `.csv` (instead of `.txt`), and it successfully added an entry for each unique Serial_Num, but it returned empty values for each key.  `2017161N13119 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'GPS': [(), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]})`

Comment: I replaced the file extensions to `.csv` and it worked for me.  Try renaming the file to `.txt`.  I suspect your csv did not separate columns correctly.

Comment: I see a different serial key in your comment.  Try to confirm whether this code works using the data I posted first.  Lmk what happens.

Comment: Same thing - I put your data in a CSV, get the same empty values.  FWIW, it looks like it's correctly getting the GPS groups, just not adding the values in the list. Your info returned: `defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'1950004S11059': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'GPS': [(), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]}), '1950012S14150': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'GPS': [(), (), (), (), (), ()]}), '1950013S14139': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'GPS': [(), ()]})})`

Comment: Did you try it as a `.txt` file?

Comment: Yep :/ ...just empty info.  FWIW I'm using your code exactly, with an added `print(data)` at the end.

Comment: Ok.  Should be fixed now for a true csv file.